# Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x^2)$ over the splitting field of $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Suppose $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $d>1$. Let $f(x^2)$ be irreducible. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x^2)$. Show that $Gal(L/K)$ is an abelian 2-group.

I know that since $f(x^2)$ irreducible, it implies that $f(x)$ is also irreducible.

From here I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If $[L:K]$ was indeed $2$ then it would trivially give you the result. However, this might not be the case. How did you come to $[L:K]=2$ anyway? Anyway, to solve the problem, think what are the roots of $f(x^2)$ if you know what are the roots of $f$.

Comment: I got mistaken for the $[L:K]=2$ part. Thanks for pointing it out. The roots of $f(x)$ are also roots $f(x^2)$. But there might be more roots for $f(x^2)$?

Comment: A root of $f(x)$ need not be a root of $f(x^2)$. $f(\alpha)=0$ doesn't necessary imply $f(\alpha^2)=0$. However, $\sqrt{\alpha}$ indeed satisfies $f((\sqrt{\alpha})^2)=f(\alpha)=0$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, let's think of an example. If $f(x)=x^2-2,$ then $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $f(x^2)=x^4-2$. This polynomial decomposes over $K$ as $(x^2-\sqrt{2})(x^2+\sqrt{2})$. $L$ is obtained as a successive quadratic extension
$$K\subset K(\sqrt[4]{2})\subset K(
\sqrt[4]{2},i\sqrt[4]{2})=K(\sqrt[4]{2},i)=L$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. We see that $$\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2.$$

The general case is the same, since $f(x^2)$ decomposes in $K$ as
$$(x^2-a_1)(x^2-a_2)\cdots(x^2-a_d)$$
and $L$ is given by
$$L=K(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{a_2},\cdots\sqrt{a_d})$$
where some of the square roots can be redundant. The Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is the set of involutions which negates appropriate $\sqrt{a_i}$'s (*), so it is in fact an abelian elementary 2-group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^e$ as stated.

Note: An example of redundant square root, thus the case $e<d$ arises for $f(x)=x^2+1$.

(*)EDIT (explanation): Let us throw those $\sqrt{a_i}$ which is already in $K(\sqrt{a_1},\dots,\sqrt{a_{i-1}})$ away and remove redundancy. By renumbering, we just denote the resulting generators of $L$ over $K$ as
$$L=K(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{a_2},\cdots\sqrt{a_e}).$$
Thus, we can assume that the successive quadratic extensions
$$K\subset K(\sqrt{a_1})\subset K(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{a_2})\subset \cdots\subset K(\sqrt{a_1},\dots,\sqrt{a_e})=L$$
are all strict inclusions. In particular, we see $[L\colon K]=2^e$ and
$L/K$ is Galois by construction.

Now, for every $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ and every $i=1,\dots,e$ we have $\sigma(\sqrt{a_i})=\pm\sqrt{a_i}$ since they are the only solutions of the minimal polynomial $x^2-a_i$ over $K$. In particular, we see that $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}_L$ for every $\sigma$. This is enough to conclude that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is elementary abelian of order $2^e$. Perhaps more directly, it is also clear that we have $\sigma\sigma'=\sigma'\sigma$ for $\sigma,\sigma'\in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. Therefore, we get the conclusion again. (Note that, a counting of elements shows that the choices of $\pm$ on $i$ can be done free of conditions, to make up $2^e$ elements.)

Comment: What does it mean when you say that the Galois group $Gal(L/K)$ is the set of involutions which negates appropriate $\sqrt{a_i}$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Toasted_Brain I edited some explanation. I hope it helps!